# Please tell me the difference b/w below three declaration-

Tags: static, final

Please tell me the difference b/w below three declaration-

1. `private static int i=10;`
2. `private static final int j=10;`
3. `private final int k = 10;`

Comment: Try googling for static and final keywords. Make an effort.

Comment: Seriously man. You have the internet at your fingertips and you can't even google this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Short answer:***

Final: you cannot change the var after the declaration.

Static: the variable is associated with a class not with instances

```
private static int i=10;        // belongs to the class
private static final int j=10;  // belongs to the class and it's unchangeable 
private final int k = 10;       // it's unchangeable
```

***Long Answer:***

**Final:** Define an entity once that cannot be changed nor derived from later. More specifically: a final class cannot be subclassed, a final method cannot be overridden, and a final variable can occur at most once as a left-hand expression. All methods in a final class are implicitly final.

**Static:** Used to declare a field, method, or inner class as a class field. Classes maintain one copy of class fields regardless of how many instances exist of that class. static also is used to define a method as a class method. Class methods are bound to the class instead of to a specific instance, and can only operate on class fields. (Classes and interfaces declared as static members of another class or interface are actually top-level classes and are not inner classes.)

Comment: Thanks Kyllopardiun !

Comment: @Faizal, if my answer helped you please consider [accepting it](http://stackoverflow.com/about) by clicking on the check mark.

Answer (score 2):

C'mon.  Just read what each keyword means:

static means "associated with a class rather than instances"

final is more complex - context dependent.

http://javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_final.shtml

```
private static int i=10;  // i is associated with class; mutable
private static final int j=10; // j is associated with class; immutable
private final int k = 10; // k is associated with instances; immutable
```

Comment: Why even honor this question with an answer?

Comment: @Takendarkk For the rep, of course!

Comment: Everyone is a beginner once.  This might be a lazy one, but that doesn't mean something useful can't be said.

Answer (score 1):

It's sometimes helpful to think of "static" in a similar way to "global".  So the differences are the following:

1. private static int i = 10;  // this means that all instances of a class will share the same variable i and whatever its current value is. E.g., Thing A and Thing B are instances of class Thing.  If A modifies the variable i, then it will be modified for B as well.
2. private static final int j = 10;  // this means that all instances of the class will share the same value for j just like number 1.  Additionally, you cannot change the value of j.  It is a constant, immutable.
3. private final int k = 10; // this means it's a constant.